# Materialize cards - columns parallel order

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, materialize

Okay guys this is the effect I want:
[image]

This is what I currently have:
[image]
You can see that the problem is with the order of the cards - columns. I've set them to 7 and 5, **but card 2 won't start until card 3 is finished**.

How do I achieve the affect as picture 1 ? I tried combining them into one row, but that just put elements under each other.

Here is the full HTML, I've marked the cards with a comment:`

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--navbar-->
        <header>
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-3">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Kviz</a>
            <!--
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li><a href="sass.html">test</a></li>
            </ul>
            -->
          </div>
        </nav>
        </header>

        <main>

<!-- THIS IS CARD 1 -->
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m12 l7 xl7">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-image">
                <img src="images/zad1slika.png">
              </div> <p style="padding: 15px; margin-top: -12px;">
              Tekstualni opis pitanja. 
              Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan….
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

<!-- THIS IS CARD 3 -->
          <div class="col s12 m12 l5 xl5">
            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
              <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
                <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
                I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a .......... TEXT</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-action">
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
                <a href="#">This is a link</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- THIS IS CARD 2 -->
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m12 l7 xl7">
                <div class="card" style="padding: 15px;">
                  <span class="card-title naslovPrijava">Obeležite jedan odgovor:</span>
                  <form action="#">
                    <div class="selectme">
                      <p>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; a) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="odg1" class="myCheckbox" />
                        <label for="odg1" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora a)</label>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; b) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="odg2" class="myCheckbox" />
                        <label for="odg2" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora b)</label>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; c) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="odg3" class="myCheckbox" />
                        <label for="odg3" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora c)</label>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; d) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="odg4" class="myCheckbox" />
                        <label for="odg4" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora d)</label>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; e) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="odg5" class="myCheckbox" />
                        <label for="odg5" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora e)</label>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; f) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="odg6" class="myCheckbox" />
                        <label for="odg6" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora f)</label>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </main>

        <footer class="page-footer  light-blue darken-4">
          <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
            <center> © 2017 VTŠ Apps Team </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

      <script>
      //Near checkboxes
      $('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
          $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      });


      //Every checkboxes in the page
      $('.selectme input:checkbox').click(function() {
          $('.selectme input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
      });  
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>`
```

You don't have to use my code. If you can create empty cards or columns that have the affect as the picture above, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my solution i edited your code

```js
//Near checkboxes
      $('.myCheckbox').click(function() {
          $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
      });


      //Every checkboxes in the page
      $('.selectme input:checkbox').click(function() {
          $('.selectme input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<header>
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-wrapper light-blue darken-3">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Kviz</a>
            <!--
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li><a href="sass.html">test</a></li>
            </ul>
            -->
          </div>
        </nav>
        </header>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l7">
    <!-- THIS IS CARD 1 -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="images/zad1slika.png">
        </div> <p style="padding: 15px; margin-top: -12px;">
        Tekstualni opis pitanja. 
        Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan…. Na slici je prikazan….
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- THIS IS CARD 2 -->
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div class="card" style="padding: 15px;">
          <span class="card-title naslovPrijava">Obeležite jedan odgovor:</span>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="selectme">
              <p>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; a) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="odg1" class="myCheckbox" />
                <label for="odg1" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora a)</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; b) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="odg2" class="myCheckbox" />
                <label for="odg2" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora b)</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; c) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="odg3" class="myCheckbox" />
                <label for="odg3" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora c)</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; d) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="odg4" class="myCheckbox" />
                <label for="odg4" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora d)</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; e) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="odg5" class="myCheckbox" />
                <label for="odg5" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora e)</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; f) &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="odg6" class="myCheckbox" />
                <label for="odg6" style="color:black;"> Tekstualni opis ponuđenog odgovora f)</label>
              </p>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12 l5">
    <!-- THIS IS CARD 3 -->
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
          I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a .......... TEXT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

        <footer class="page-footer  light-blue darken-4">
          <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
            <center> © 2017 VTŠ Apps Team </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
```

The full screen is 12 columns so i divide it in tow, the first is 7 columns and the second is 5.

i placed card 3 in the second half, next i create a new row in the firs half and the it became 12 columns so i placed card 1 with 12 columns and next to it card 3 with 12 columns (12 +12 =24 the columns push each others in a way they make 2 rows in one row)

Answer (score 0):

You can use float, absolute positioning or flex. Here is one approach with flexbox:

```css
.layout {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.card {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.left {
  flex: 7 0;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.right {
  flex: 5 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="card top">Card 1
    </div>
    <div class="card bottom">Card 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card right">Card 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Read (and bookmark) this two articles:

- [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)